# Plural or Singular After a List of Items

Tags: grammatical-number

Given the sentence:

> The password must be at least 8 characters long, contain at least one lower-case and one upper-case case **letter(s)** and a digit.

Should the word "letter(s)" be in singular or plural? Why?

EDIT: To avoid discussion on the password policies, please consider another example:

> Today I've seen one yellow, one blue and one green **bird(s)**.

Comment: You say it's one. One is singular. One letter. Not one letters.

Comment: Yes, but both letters are required so 1+1=2 -> plural?

Comment: @VilmantasBaranauskas: You want math? Try this: 1 lc letter + 1 uc letter = (1 lc + 1 uc) letter

Comment: This is one of those awkward cases where grammatical number doesn't necessarily track with intuition.  By saying "one lower-case and one upper-case letter", you are saying "one lower-case letter and one upper-case letter".  If your phrase was "two lower-case and two upper-case", then you would use "letters".

Comment: Its singular: "contain at least (one lower-case) and (one upper-case case) **letter** and a digit." -->  "contain at least (one lower-case **letter**) and (one upper-case case **letter**) and a digit."  The word *letter* is merely a common factor stated separately to avoid repetition.

Comment: @Vlimantas: yes, *both are* required. But you do not say "both" in your sentence. In your sentence, you say "one". One is singular. I don't understand how people with a straight face can call this "awkward" or "against intuition". It is very simple and logical. Two are. Both are. One is.

Comment: And it's the same in every language I can think of, by the way. It's not like English is sticking out.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The nail that sticks out gets hammered down.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid sounding awkward and perhaps being ambiguous, I would recommend rephrasing your requirement.

> The password must be at least 8 characters long and contain: at least one lowercase letter, at least one uppercase letter, and at least one digit.

To add my own input, this sort of password requirement will also tend to require at least one symbol and it should also list the acceptable symbols.

Comment: No need to repeat the word *letter,* it can be factored out. In any case, rephrasing is not the answer.

Answer (score -1):

When the particular password contains one upper and one lower case letter, the word use would be letter (singular form). If that particular passwords contains more then either one upper or lower case letter, it will become letters (plural form).